# How to make an SQL query from a clickable image in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, sql

I'm setting up a new Web-Site and i want to ask you about a function that i want to add.

I have a page that the user can delete a product (row from MySQLi table)

So far i add an image that is changed on hover

```
   <hmtl>
   ...
   <h6>
     <div class="Delete_product">
      //here user can press the delete image 
      // and i want to make an SQL Query like
      // "DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`product_id` = 8"
     </div>

    </html>
```

and the CSS that changes the delete image on hover

```
css

.Delete_product                   {
   background-image:url('../code/Images/Buttons/DELETE.png');
   width: 330px; 
   height: 40px;
   background-position:center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;   }

.Delete_product:hover              {
  background-image:url('../code/Images/Buttons/DELETE_active2.png');
  width: 330px; 
  height: 40px;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;    }
```

How to execute the SQL DELETE Query when the user press DELETE (image) and in second time ask him again

(like: are you sure that you want to delete this product)

Comment: Google and learn about Ajax.

Comment: @bassxzero oh now you help me a lot. What i would do without you

Comment: Some would say I'm a godsend.

Comment: Some would say that you dont know the answer and make ironic comments.

Comment: at least 2 people would say otherwise.

Comment: This feels really like 5 questions in one: `.onclick`, `.style()`, `confirm()`, `$.post()`, `$db->query()`.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Downvoted for 0 effort put into trying to figure this out before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX.

```
$.post(
      'YOUR SCRIPT URL',
        {idToDelete : $(".Delete_product").data('idToDelete')},
        function(data){
          //do something if you wants
        }
    );
```

In your php script, take the POST parameter to create SQL request with the ID parameter for example.

For the confirmation message, you can display a modal on click on element, when he pressed the accept button, run your ajax request.